# C program cannot output a proper value with user created function

Tags: c

I tried to write a program that ask user two inputs and then calculate a volume. However, the program keeps giving me 0.00000.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define PI 3.14159


float calvolume(float rad, float h)
{

return (1/3)*PI*pow(rad,2)*h;

}



int main()
{
float radius, height, volume;

printf("Please enter a radius: \n");
scanf("%f",&radius);

printf("Please enter a height: \n");
scanf("%f",&height);

volume = calvolume(radius,height);

printf("The volume is : %f \n",volume);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `1/3` is integer division and is exactly `0`. You need floating point types, e.g. `1/3.0`.

Comment: A really useful habit for programmers is to multiply before dividing. This is mathematically equivalent, and it does not have the error of integer division: `PI*pow(rad,2)*h/3`

Answer (score 2):

```
 return (1/3)*PI*pow(rad,2)*h;

   (1/3) means zero
```

integer division is zero. Make it

```
 return (1.0f/3.0f)*PI*pow(rad,2.0f)*h;
 1.0f to avoid promotion, being probably faster.
```

Better yet:

```
 return (0.333333333f)*PI*pow(rad,2.0f)*h;
```

Even better:

```
 return (0.333333333f)*PI*rad*rad*h;
```

Comment: Better yet, move the division to the back of the formula :-)

Comment: Yes, the order may seem better but I just cancelled the division.

Comment: Well, the compiler would do the same thing with your `(1f/3f)` expression, too.

Comment: So all these are just premature optimization and source of evil? Or  should we stay hungry, stay foolish?

Comment: I usually go with whatever correct representation that reads better on the screen, and let the compiler optimize it for me. By "better" I mean "close to what one would see in a book or in a web article", because I am terrible at memorizing the formulas.

Comment: Then the (1/3) was true but it should be re-defined as 1f/3f

Comment: `1.f/3` and `0.333333333f` are different numbers

Comment: `#define (1/3) (1f/3f)` is not valid syntax